# Is there something wrong with my large tables join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing the following query:

```
UPDATE extlinks
INNER JOIN sp_board using (title)
SET extlinks.board_id = sp_board.id
```

Both `title` columns are an index, as well as the `board_id` column and the `id` column (which is a primary index). `extlinks` has 6.45 million rows, while `sp_board` has about 3.7 million rows. Both tables are Innodb.

I started this join over an hour ago, and it still hasn't finished. Is this normal? If yes, how long can I expect it to take? If not, any ideas on what could be wrong?

TIA!

Comment: Normal. Especially if you are using InnoDB ... MySQL has to do a transaction for your update, which has a lot of overhead. Be patient.

Comment: I am not sure if this syntax correct. Did you mean to link the JOINed tables somehow? I thought you would use ON extlinks.someID = sp_board.someID befor your SET clause

Comment: @cha when both columns have the same name you can use USING instead of ON

Comment: @OllieJones you were right, I just had to wait :-). Can you turn your comment into and answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few hours running time is normal for a large update. If you're using InnoDB the MySQL server has to generate a transaction for your update, so it can roll it back if need be. That takes a lot of overhead. Your server is probably using a lot of RAM and IO during this operation.

Just wait a bit.